# Cron job is not running the php script

Tags: php, cron

I have created a cron job in my cpanel using command below:

/usr/bin/php -q /home/user/public_html/folder/subfolder/sync.php

The content of syns.php is almost like this. It works without error when I run it with the domain like domain.com/folder/subfolder/sync.php but I can not see the expected result when the cron job supposed to run which means cron job is not running the script. So can anyone tell me what might be the problem?

```
<?php

$dir = str_replace("public_html","", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
$dir = $dir . "configuration.php";

if (file_exists($dir)) 
{
    require_once($dir);
    sync();
} 
else
{
    // echo ("Can't find the access data.");
}

function sync()
{
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        // echo ("Failed to connect the database.");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        if(mysqli_ping($connection))
        {
            $query = "SELECT OR UPDATE WHATEAVER FROM TABLE;";
            $result = mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query);
            if($result)
            {
                // Do stuff
            }
            else
            {
                // echo("Failed to excute the query.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // echo("Failed to ping the connection.");
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is created by your webserver (e.g. Apache) before calling PHP. If you're running your script via a cronjob, you're bypassing your webserver and the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` will not exist.

You should determine the location of your configuration file in another way. One way is to use PHP's built-in constants for file locations, like `__FILE__` or `__DIR__`:

```
$dir = __DIR__ . "/configuration.php";
```

`__DIR__` refers to the folder containing the current file, so this will become `/home/user/public_html/folder/subfolder/configuration.php`.

From what you're doing with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` I assume your configuration file is one folder up from `public_html`, so you could do something like this:

```
$dir = __DIR__ . "/../../../configuration.php";
```

Comment: I changed the $dir but still nothing. But it will send me an email every time that it's trying to run and the email says "Could not open input file". Any advice?

Comment: That sounds like a bash error, not a PHP one. Check to make sure PHP is actually in `/usr/bin/php` and double-check the full path to your `sync.php` file in your cron settings. Also, are you able to SSH into the server and try to execute the full command from there?